# Using Flexbox with jQueryUI's sortable

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, flexbox

I've been working on a UI recently and I really like to use Flexbox CSS for control of the layout. I needed a way to make the boxes I have be sortable and draggable.

I started by trying out **jQueryUI's sortable** but it doesn't seem to work very well with flexbox. **It does sort but I think its got some calculation errors in regards to when its droppable in the new location?** Either that or I'm doing something wrong. **Either way I'll provide my code and a JSFiddle so you can see for yourself the weirdness**. The behavior I'm looking for is nice clean droppable placeholders and for the alignment to be like how jQueryUI's example is. **To test click and drag on the legends.** Also try dragging the left most item to the far right.

How can I solve this such that it will work with Flexbox?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/95pv6cn2/5/

Compare this with jQueryUI and how its supposed to operate (https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#placeholder)

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <div class="header">
     <div class="logo">Sample Login System</div>
     <div class="logoutarea">
       <div class="loggedInAs">Logged in as (joe).</div>
       <div class="logout">Logout</div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="content">
     <div class="actionarea" id="sortable">
       <div class="statusset">
         <fieldset>
           <legend>Status:</legend>
           <div class="startbtn" status="off">Start Taking Calls/Text</div>
           <div class="callstatusarea">
             <span class="callstatusheader">Call/Text Status:</span>
             <span class="status" status="free">Free</span>
           </div>
         </fieldset>
       </div>
       <div class="textmessageset">
         <fieldset>
           <legend>Send Outbound Text Message:</legend>
           <div class="inputline sendtextfrom">
             <div class="label">Send Text From:</div>
             <select class="fromselect">                                  
               <option value="+19998887777">+19998887777</option>
               <option value="+16665554444">+16665554444</option>
             </select>
           </div>   
           <div class="inputline sendtextto">
             <div class="label">Send Text To:</div>
             <input class="phoneinput sendtexttoinput" type="text" placeholder="To Phone Number..."/>
           </div>
           <div class="inputline sendtextresponsebackto">
             <div class="label">Response Number: </div>  
             <input class="phoneinput sendtextresponsebackinput" type="text" placeholder="Your Phone Number..." title="(If no response back number given or response back number known to be busy in the system, then the system will automatically determine who to send text to)"/>
           </div>
           <div class="inputline sendtextwithmessage">
             <div class="label">With Message:</div>
             <textarea class="sendtextwithmessage_textarea" placeholder="Enter text message here..."></textarea>
           </div>
           <div class="inputline sendtextwithpicture">
             <div class="label">Media URL:</div>
             <input class="sendtextpictureurlinput" type="text" placeholder="http://a.com/image.jpg"/>
           </div>
           <button class="sendtextbtn">Send Outbound Text</button>
         </fieldset>
       </div>
       <div class="otherset">
         <fieldset>
           <legend>Some Other Random Set:</legend>
           Here is some text
         </fieldset>
       </div>
       <div class="callset">
         <fieldset>
           <legend>Start Outbound Call:</legend>
           <div class="inputline sendcallfrom">
             <div class="label">Caller ID From:</div>
             <select class="fromcalleridselect">
                <option value="+19998887777">+19998887777</option>
               <option value="+16665554444">+16665554444</option>
             </select>
           </div>
           <div class="inputline sendcallto">
             <div class="label">Send Call To:</div>
             <input class="phoneinput sendcalltoinput" type="text" placeholder="To Phone Number..."/>
           </div>
           <div class="inputline andMyPhone">
             <div class="label">Initiate To My Phone:</div>
             <input class="phoneinput initiatecalltomyphoneinput" type="text" placeholder="My Phone Number..."/>
           </div>
           <button class="inputline startoutboundcallbtn">Start Outbound Call</button>
         </fieldset>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="footer">
     &copy; 2017 Sample Company LLC
   </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
/*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */
/**
 * 1. Set default font family to sans-serif.
 * 2. Prevent iOS and IE text size adjust after device orientation change,
 *    without disabling user zoom.
 */
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* 1 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
}
/**
 * Remove default margin.
 */
body {
  margin: 0;
}
/* HTML5 display definitions
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * Correct `block` display not defined for any HTML5 element in IE 8/9.
 * Correct `block` display not defined for `details` or `summary` in IE 10/11
 * and Firefox.
 * Correct `block` display not defined for `main` in IE 11.
 */
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}
/**
 * 1. Correct `inline-block` display not defined in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Normalize vertical alignment of `progress` in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
 */
audio,
canvas,
progress,
video {
  display: inline-block;
  /* 1 */
  vertical-align: baseline;
  /* 2 */
}
/**
 * Prevent modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */
audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}
/**
 * Address `[hidden]` styling not present in IE 8/9/10.
 * Hide the `template` element in IE 8/9/10/11, Safari, and Firefox < 22.
 */
[hidden],
template {
  display: none;
}
/* Links
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * Remove the gray background color from active links in IE 10.
 */
a {
  background-color: transparent;
}
/**
 * Improve readability of focused elements when they are also in an
 * active/hover state.
 */
a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}
/* Text-level semantics
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 8/9/10/11, Safari, and Chrome.
 */
abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
/**
 * Address style set to `bolder` in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */
b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
/**
 * Address styling not present in Safari and Chrome.
 */
dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}
/**
 * Address variable `h1` font-size and margin within `section` and `article`
 * contexts in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}
/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 8/9.
 */
mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}
/**
 * Address inconsistent and variable font size in all browsers.
 */
small {
  font-size: 80%;
}
/**
 * Prevent `sub` and `sup` affecting `line-height` in all browsers.
 */
sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}
sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}
/* Embedded content
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 8/9/10.
 */
img {
  border: 0;
}
/**
 * Correct overflow not hidden in IE 9/10/11.
 */
svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* Grouping content
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * Address margin not present in IE 8/9 and Safari.
 */
figure {
  margin: 1em 40px;
}
/**
 * Address differences between Firefox and other browsers.
 */
hr {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
}
/**
 * Contain overflow in all browsers.
 */
pre {
  overflow: auto;
}
/**
 * Address odd `em`-unit font size rendering in all browsers.
 */
code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
}
/* Forms
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * Known limitation: by default, Chrome and Safari on OS X allow very limited
 * styling of `select`, unless a `border` property is set.
 */
/**
 * 1. Correct color not being inherited.
 *    Known issue: affects color of disabled elements.
 * 2. Correct font properties not being inherited.
 * 3. Address margins set differently in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */
button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  color: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  font: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  margin: 0;
  /* 3 */
}
/**
 * Address `overflow` set to `hidden` in IE 8/9/10/11.
 */
button {
  overflow: visible;
}
/**
 * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
 * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
 * Correct `button` style inheritance in Firefox, IE 8/9/10/11, and Opera.
 * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox.
 */
button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}
/**
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 */
button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 2 */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* 3 */
}
/**
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */
button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}
/**
 * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 4+.
 */
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/**
 * Address Firefox 4+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */
input {
  line-height: normal;
}
/**
 * It's recommended that you don't attempt to style these elements.
 * Firefox's implementation doesn't respect box-sizing, padding, or width.
 *
 * 1. Address box sizing set to `content-box` in IE 8/9/10.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9/10.
 */
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 2 */
}
/**
 * Fix the cursor style for Chrome's increment/decrement buttons. For certain
 * `font-size` values of the `input`, it causes the cursor style of the
 * decrement button to change from `default` to `text`.
 */
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}
/**
 * 1. Address `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari and Chrome.
 * 2. Address `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari and Chrome.
 */
input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  /* 1 */
  box-sizing: content-box;
  /* 2 */
}
/**
 * Remove inner padding and search cancel button in Safari and Chrome on OS X.
 * Safari (but not Chrome) clips the cancel button when the search input has
 * padding (and `textfield` appearance).
 */
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
/**
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */
fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}
/**
 * 1. Correct `color` not being inherited in IE 8/9/10/11.
 * 2. Remove padding so people aren't caught out if they zero out fieldsets.
 */
legend {
  border: 0;
  /* 1 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 2 */
}
/**
 * Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE 8/9/10/11.
 */
textarea {
  overflow: auto;
}
/**
 * Don't inherit the `font-weight` (applied by a rule above).
 * NOTE: the default cannot safely be changed in Chrome and Safari on OS X.
 */
optgroup {
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* Tables
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 0;
}
/* Main.Less */
.header {
  height: 20px;
  background: #1e5799;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: space-around;
  align-items: space-around;
}
.footer {
  height: 20px;
  background: #b3dced;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b3dced 0%, #29b8e5 50%, #bce0ee 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b3dced 0%, #29b8e5 50%, #bce0ee 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b3dced 0%, #29b8e5 50%, #bce0ee 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#b3dced', endColorstr='#bce0ee', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
.logoutarea {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: space-around;
  align-items: space-around;
  text-align: right;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.loggedInAs {
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}
.logout {
  text-align: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 30px;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}
.logout:hover {
  color: blue;
}
.logo {
  width: 100%;
  align-self: center;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
}
.error {
  color: blue;
}
/* Sticky Footer */
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
}
/* End Sticky Footer */
.startbtn {
  display: inline-box;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
.startbtn[status="off"] {
  background: #34d960;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #34d960, #139e54);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #34d960, #139e54);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #34d960, #139e54);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #34d960, #139e54);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #34d960, #139e54);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #666666;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.startbtn[status="on"] {
  background: #e62020;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e62020, #bd1b1b);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e62020, #bd1b1b);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e62020, #bd1b1b);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e62020, #bd1b1b);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e62020, #bd1b1b);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #666666;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.startbtn:hover[status="off"] {
  background: #58a862;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #58a862, #2d472d);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #58a862, #2d472d);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #58a862, #2d472d);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #58a862, #2d472d);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #58a862, #2d472d);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.startbtn:hover[status="on"] {
  background: #de2a3c;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #de2a3c, #4d2323);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #de2a3c, #4d2323);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #de2a3c, #4d2323);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #de2a3c, #4d2323);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #de2a3c, #4d2323);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.callstatusheader {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
.callstatusarea {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
.callstatusarea .status {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.callstatusarea .status[status="free"] {
  color: green;
}
.callstatusarea .status[status="busy"] {
  color: red;
}
.callstatusarea .unbusy[status="free"] {
  display: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.callstatusarea .unbusy[status="busy"] {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.callstatusarea .unbusy:hover {
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: blue;
}
.actionarea {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.actionarea .label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 125px;
}
.actionarea input {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.actionarea select {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.actionarea textarea {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.actionarea button {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.actionarea legend {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.actionarea .inputline {
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.actionarea .textmessageset {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 500px;
}
.actionarea .callset {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 500px;
}
.actionarea .otherset {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 500px;
}
.actionarea .statusset {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 500px;
}
.ui-state-highlight {
  width: 50px;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //@JA - Logout Fuction
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: It looks like flexbox is behaving as it should. Once the element is being dragged, it's getting an absolute position and breaking out of the flow.

You may want to look into wrapping divs with explicit widths (and maybe even heights) to preserve the flex dimensions, then clean it up once the component is "dropped."

Comment: Try grabbing the left most item to the far right

Comment: http://www.giphy.com/gifs/xUA7bjv056ovaRa1Da Okay, this is what I see. What specifically is not working?

I see that when I pick up the element, the space it previously contained drops to nothing and takes up the width of the placeholder. Then when I drop it to be the third item, it wraps to the next row.

Comment: Are you saying its because the containing elements need to maintain their widths? If so let me play around with the jsfiddle to see if it can fix it

Comment: Yes. Flexbox is going to fit everything it can into a row, and since you have `flex-wrap: wrap` on the `.actionarea`, if it can fit another element in there, it will. Since your droppable highlight is narrow, more elements can fit on the row. -- So you can either look into having the wrapper maintain it's width, or have the highlight have a larger width, perhaps that of the element being dragged.

Comment: Ok give me some time to test this out.

Comment: I'm still confused how to make this work, do you think you could modify the JSFiddle to show me an example?

Comment: I was able to get it working if I change flex direction to column but then it won't work horizontally

Comment: The trick is making this work while still keeping the flex-wrap

Comment: here is latest jsfiddle I was messing with (https://jsfiddle.net/95pv6cn2/18/)

Comment: going right to left works nicely, its going left to right that doesn't for some reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139718/discussion-between-christian-hain-and-joseph-astrahan).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use some of sortable's event handlers to create a "ghost" element in place of the element you are moving. This will help preserve the flex calculations.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/CRHain88/vv636vj4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //@JA - Logout Fuction

  // Create a reusable spacer element. I added a background
  // style to give indication that there was once something
  // there. If you're going to style it with more complex
  // design, consider making it have it's own class.
  var placeholderElement = jQuery('<div style="background-color: #eee;"></div>');

  $("#sortable").sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",

    // Add it before the element you're dragging.
    // This assumes that you can only ever drag one element at a time.
    activate: function(event, ui) {
      placeholderElement.insertBefore(ui.item[0]);

      // Explicitly set the height and width to preserve
      // flex calculations
      placeholderElement.width(ui.item[0].offsetWidth);
      placeholderElement.height(ui.item[0].offsetHeight);
    },

    // Remove it when you're done dragging.
    deactivate: function() {
      placeholderElement.remove();
    }
  });

  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery sortable DOES have the capability to handle horizontal lists like this, but to activate that behaviour it looks for items to be either `float: left|right;`, `display: inline;` or `display: table-cell;`. Here's where the check happens in jQuery UI 1.12.1

```
    _isFloating: function( item ) {
        return ( /left|right/ ).test( item.css( "float" ) ) ||
            ( /inline|table-cell/ ).test( item.css( "display" ) );
    },
```

I applied `float: left;` to your code and I think it behaves a little better now:
https://jsfiddle.net/1s24xpzu/

It's not a pretty solution as we're basically just tricking jQuery, and there could be unintended floaty consequences. But I think it will work for my use-case at least.

Answer (score 0):

For those that stumbled upon this like me:

My use-case was that I wanted to sort a list of items ordered inside a flexbox row. I tried the solutions above, and they did nothing. I also tried adding a float to the first element (as that is what it detects), but that didn't help all that much.

What I did instead is change the `isFloat` function (mind you, this should be called `isHorizontalSort`) like this:

```
_isFloating: function( item ) {
        return ( /left|right/ ).test( item.css( "float" )) ||
            ( /inline|table-cell/ ).test( item.css( "display" )) ||
            (
                ( /flex/ ).test( item.parent().css( "display" )) && ( /row|row-reverse/ ).test( item.parent().css( "flex-direction" ) )
            )
    },
```

so it detects if the child is inside a horizontal flexbox (flex direction is row or row-reverse). I've also set the `tolerance` option as `pointer`, which seems to give the best results.

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/edgolub/pen/RzGgWZ

Comment: It's not ideal to edit a third-party package.  What worked for me was retaining the flexbox styles but additionally adding style: ```float: left``` on the sortable items.  The float style did no harm and allowed jQueryUI sortable to sort normally.

Answer (score 0):

Christian's answer did not work for me but led me to this solution:

```
activate: function(event, ui) {
   $('.ui-sortable-placeholder').width(ui.item[0].offsetWidth).height(ui.item[0].offsetHeight);
},
```

It seems that the plugin already adds a placeholder with this class. All I needed was to set its size. Otherwise it created an enormous placeholder and moved everything.